# $\dfrac{O(1)}{x} = O(\dfrac{1}{x})$?

Tags: estimation, upper-lower-bounds

I just saw a lecture where the professor did this simplification in a proof but did not comment it further. How would you go about provning the statement in the title?

Answer (score 2):

For the $x\to\infty$ case, the following statements are equivalent:

- $f\in\frac{O(1)}{x}$
- $xf\in O(1)$
- There exist $x_0,\,M$ with $M>0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, $|xf(x)|<M$
- There exist $x_0,\,M$ with $M>0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, $|f(x)|<M|1/x|$
- $f\in O(1/x)$

You can handle $x\to0$ or $x\to0^+$ similarly.

Comment: I cant follow the proof. Is it possible to produce some proof which does not use so much logical symbols?

Comment: @VictorGaleabo As requested, I've removed the $\forall,\exists$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can follow now. Could this be considered a proof: let $h(x) = \dfrac{O(1)}{x} \Leftrightarrow x\cdot h(x) = O(1)$ meaning specifically $x\cdot h(x) \le K\cdot 1\Leftrightarrow h(x) le K\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$ for some constant $K$. Thus $h(x) = O(1/x)$.

Comment: @VictorGaleano Those forward slashes need to be back slashes for the LaTeX to work, but my main tips regarding the proof concern including moduli & the $x_0,\,M$ preambles.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be considered a proof: let $h(x) = \dfrac{O(1)}{x} \Leftrightarrow x\cdot h(x) = O(1)$ meaning specifically $x\cdot h(x) \le  K\cdot 1\Leftrightarrow h(x) \le K\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$ for some constant $K$. Thus $h(x) = O(1/x)$.